# Promises with SequelizeJS

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js, es6-promise

I need to use promises with SequelizeJS but I want to make sure that my code is clean...

My code :

```
  var items = request.body.items,
      promises;

  promises = _.map(items, function(item) {
    return ProjectModel.findById(item.id).then(function(findedProject) {

      ProjectPhotoModel.findAll({ where: { projectId: findedProject.id } }).then(function(findedPhotos) {

        var photoPromises = _.map(findedPhotos, function(photo) {
          fs.unlink('./public/uploads/' + photo.name, function() {
            photo.destroy();
          });
        });

        Promise.all(photoPromises);

      });

      fs.unlink('./public/uploads/' + findedProject.thumbnail, function() {
        findedProject.destroy();
      });

    });
  });

  Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
    response.send('');
  });
```

How to use nested promises ?

Comment: Does the current code work?

Comment: Nested promises are something you usually want to avoid - check out http://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/

Comment: Yes my code works but I just would like to make sure that my code is the best way to use promises... Thank you for your advice about nested promises.